# How to add paragraph after an image in css

Tags: html, css, paragraph

Nav Bar(sticky)
image(position: absolute;)
some text(inside the image)
paragraph

problem is- the paragraph is floating on the image.
tried "clear:both" 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/PqH7PhRJQnk1WLmT7
https://photos.app.goo.gl/FM87Wwxnfj8hCG2K6

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Dont use image position as absolute try using it as fixed. Fixing as absolute without any pos. specifications will make text appear over image